# Creating an object within an object, is it good coding practice? (PHP)

Tags: oop

I'm just going to show what I mean, and I want to know whether it is good coding practices or should I try to avoid it?

```
class Connector {
    public function __constructer ($ip, $port)
    {
        $this->socket = fsockopen($ip, $port); // Forgive me, this is simply just example, never going to be used in real-life

        return $this->socket;
    }

    public function getInfo()
    {
        // return information which maybe properties of the server the ip is connected too
    }
}

// I just want the class Connector to handle the connection, and keep it running


// Query will be used for use of the application itself and I don't want to extend connector

class Query {
    protected $connection;

    public function connect ($ip, $port)
    {
        $this->connection = new Connector($ip, $port);
    }

    public function showInfo()
    {
        return echo $this->connection->getInfo();
    }
}
```

Please do understand, this code is not for any kind of use, it's just a small example of something more logical which I'm not posting here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is a good practice but you can make it more flexible:

```
class Query {
    protected $connection;

    public function connect (Connector $connector)
    {
        $this->connection = $connector
    }

    public function showInfo()
    {
        return $this->connection->getInfo();
    }
}
```

This is what we call Dependency Injection.

and even more flexible would be using an interface:

```
interface ConnectorInterface
{
    public function __construct(array $options);
    public function showInfo();
}
```

and then create one or more classes that implements the interface:

```
class Connector implements ConnectorInterface
{
    private $ip;
    private $port;

    public function __construct(array $options)
    {
        $this->ip = $options['ip'];
        $this->port = $options['port'];
    }

    public function getInfo()
    {
        return 'basic connector';
    }
}

class AdvancedConnector implements ConnectorInterface
{
    private $ip;
    private $port;
    private $protocol;

    public function __construct(array $options)
    {
        $this->ip = $options['ip'];
        $this->port = $options['port'];
        $this->protocol = $options['protocol'];
    }

    public function getInfo()
    {
        return 'advanced connector';
    }
}
```

and then accept any class that implements ConnectorInterface into the Query::connect method:

```
class Query {
    protected $connection;

    // changed the parameter to ConnectorInterface !!!
    public function connect (ConnectorInterface $connector)
    {
        $this->connection = $connector
    }

    public function showInfo()
    {
        return echo $this->connection->getInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: In other words, no, it's not great practice. Use dependency injection and/or Interfaces where possible.